# Update Cascading Dropdown in Mvc5

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi i want to know how to update or edit cascading dropdown like (Country,state,City)in mvc5.I have created 3 cascading dropdowns Country State city.If i select Country State will append in state dropdownn like wise city. Now i save these 3 dropdown values in table successfully. But now i stuck with edit option. I donno how to bind the saved value to these dropdowns in edit from.

My model

```
public class UCustomerManagementViewModel
{

    public string UCountry { get; set; }
    public string UState { get; set; }
    public string UCity { get; set; }
  }
```

My Controller code

```
    public JsonResult GetCountries()
    {
        var Countries = db.Countries.ToList();
        return Json(Countries, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetStatesByCountryID(string countryId)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(countryId);
        var states = db.States.Where(d => d.CountryID == id).Select(e => new { e.UID, e.StateName }).ToList();
        return Json(states, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetCityByStateID(string stateId)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(stateId);
        var Cities = db.Cities.Where(d => d.StateID == id).Select(e => new { e.UID, e.CityName }).ToList();
        return Json(Cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }



public ActionResult Update(int id)
    {

        CustomerManagement cc = db.CustomerManagements.Find(id);
        ViewBag.CountryID = new SelectList(db.Countries.Where(d => d.CountryID.ToString() == cc.Country.ToString()), "CountryID", "CountryName",cc.CountryID);


        var ucusmanvm = new UCustomerManagementViewModel();
        ucusmanvm.UCountry = cc.Country;(here i get value 1)
        ucusmanvm.UState = cc.State;(here i get value 2)
        ucusmanvm.UCity = cc.City;(here iget value 2)
        return View(ucusmanvm);
    }
```

here i pass all the value to view form

My View Code

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCountries", "FrmCustomerManagement")',
        datatype: "Json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $('#dropdownCountry').append('<option value="' + value.CountryID + '">' + value.CountryName + '</option>');


            });
        }
    });
    $('#dropdownCountry').change(function () {
        debugger;
        $('#dropdownState').empty();
        var cval = $('#dropdownCountry').val()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetStatesByCountryID", "FrmCustomerManagement")',
            datatype: "Json",
            data: { countryId: cval },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#dropdownState').append('<option value="' + value.UID + '">' + value.StateName + '</option>');


                });
            }
        })



    });

    $('#dropdownState').change(function () {
        debugger;
        $('#dropdownCity').empty();
        var sval = $('#dropdownState').val()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCityByStateID", "FrmCustomerManagement")',
            datatype: "Json",
            data: { stateId: sval },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#dropdownCity').append('<option value="' + value.UID + '">' + value.CityName + '</option>');

                });
            }
        })
    });





     @Html.DropDownList("dropdownCountry", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a country", new { @class = "form-control", @width = "80%", @value=Model.UCountry})
    <div class="col-sm-8">
         <label>State</label>
           @Html.DropDownList("dropdownState", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a State", new { @class = "form-control", @width = "80%" , @value=Model.UState})

          </div>
         <div class="col-sm-8">
          <label>City</label>
          @Html.DropDownList("dropdownCity", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a City", new { @class = "form-control", @width = "80%" , @value=Model.Ucity})

          </div>
```

Here in update from also i acheive Cascading dropdown using ajax. but in update form i donno how to bring the save value to drop downs(Country city, state) from controller to view (eg i saved UAE in Country Dropdown but in edit mode i donno how to bring UAE value in Country dropdown ).I passed value from controller but i donno how to bind that value in view.please any one help me to resolve this issue .